# Javascript Changing Spellcheck Attribute Doesn't Update Display

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea with the `spellcheck` property set to `false` initially, and there are no red lines, as expected. When I change the property to `true`, the lines appear, again as expected.

However, once I set the property to `false` again, the red lines do not update. I was wondering why this is, or if anyone knows of a workaround or way to get the CSS to update.

Without Spellcheck:

[image: textarea without spellcheck red lines]

With Spellcheck (but then again without spellcheck):

[image: textarea with spellcheck red lines]

---

Here's my full relevant code:

```js
spellcheck.onclick = () => {
  notes.focus();
  notes.spellcheck = !notes.spellcheck;
  spellcheckonoff.textContent = notes.spellcheck ? ' on' : ' off';
}
```

```html
<textarea id="notes" placeholder="Type here" spellcheck="false" autofocus></textarea>
<button id="spellcheck" type="button">spellcheck <span id="spellcheckonoff">off</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround answer I found is, after setting `notes.spellcheck = false`, I just basically cut and paste the textarea, which sort of reloads it:

```
        let tmp = notes.value;
        notes.value = "";
        notes.value = tmp;
```

Obviously doesn't prevent the bug from happening, and might not scale well if the document is super huge, but it definitely works, and it's easy to understand and implement.